# Mounting a MyCloud share to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nfs, nas

After following a bunch of links online, I've still been unable to get MyCloud to mount with my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

It seems to be a permissions issue, but Im not sure how to fix it or add the username

This is the command I'm using:

```
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.1.110:/Media /media/Plex
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.110:/Media
```

If I try and add a username I get this error

```
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.1.110:/Media /media/Plex -o username=midnight
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Im not sure if this helps, but I was able to get SSH access setup. On the Nas is an account named 'midnight' with full admin rights and RW access to the 'media' share.

```
root@WDMyCloud root # id midnight
uid=500(midnight) gid=1000(share) groups=1000(share),1001(administrators),2000(cloudholders)
```

My ubuntu box has the same username, different UUID.

```
$id midnight
uid=1000(midnight) gid=1000(midnight) groups=1000(midnight),4(adm),6(disk),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),131(sambashare)
```

and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo mount -t nfs -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.1.110:/Media /media/Plex` ..also there is no mount option like `username`..

Comment: '$ sudo mount -t nfs -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.1.110:/Media /media/Plex
[sudo] password for midnight: 
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting

Comment: F$%^ me.   Ok.  After a few days of gnashing my teeth, I figured it out.  Such a stupid mistake.   In the NAS setup under the NFS options,  there is a field to set the IP address of the computer you want to have access.  I THOUGHT my PC was set to a static IP address, 192.168.1.103,  however after setting the option to *(allow all ip's)   it worked.  Turns out for whatever reason, my PC decided to go with DHCP.  Its Ip address was 192.168.1.101.  The access denied was based on the IP address..not the user name.   Some shoot me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of gnashing my teeth, I figured it out. Such a stupid mistake. In the NAS setup under the NFS options, there is a field to set the IP address of the computer you want to have access. I THOUGHT my PC was set to a static IP address, 192.168.1.103, however after setting the option to *(allow all ip's) it worked. Turns out for whatever reason, my PC decided to go with DHCP. Its Ip address was 192.168.1.101. The access denied was based on the IP address..not the user name

Answer (score 0):

LS again.

further to this last week Ubuntu brought out a new kernel.
This Sunday I just installed it, and it broke my nfs connection.
And the messages are indeed about, me not having rights on my own NAS.
Very coincidental you just tried your hand at nfs.

So my fstab recipe line only works with the prior kernel and your attempt might as well work with that kernel. Which you can easly switch to in the grub start up screen.

I went back to:
ijbd@zen:~$ uname -a
Linux zen 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and bingo it works again. And apparently, it was not WD to be blamed. Sorry.

Perhaps the longer start-up time of the new kernel causes time out of the fstab command lines.

regards Boudewijn

Comment: After a few days of gnashing my teeth, I figured it out. Such a stupid mistake. In the NAS setup under the NFS options, there is a field to set the IP address of the computer you want to have access. I THOUGHT my PC was set to a static IP address, 192.168.1.103, however after setting the option to *(allow all ip's) it worked. Turns out for whatever reason, my PC decided to go with DHCP. Its Ip address was 192.168.1.101. The access denied was based on the IP address..not the user name